# Split variable length string into multiple columns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have 2 tables `A` and `B`. Data in table `A` has a string which I would like to split into different columns based on `"#___-"` (`abc`,`xyz`, `efg` etc) and copy it into table `B`. The string size of table `A` will vary for every row

Table A:

```
Create table A ( data varchar(100));

Insert table A
  values ('101,#abc-sds)dfgd)3453)#xyz-hju)dddjfj)eieei)2323');
Insert into A
  values ('102,#abc-ddeff)errr)3434)#xyz-bnhb)hehe)333)#abc-dew)weerr)2343)#efg-3434)34');

Create table B ( id number, abc varchar2(50), xyz varchar2(50),
  efg varchar2(50));
```

Output of table B:

```
  ID  | ABC              |  XYZ                    |  EFG
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
  101 | sds)dfgd)3453)   | hju)dddjfj)eieei)2323   | 
  102 | ddeff)errr)3434) | bnhb)hehe)333)          | 3434)34
  102 | dew)weerr)2343)  | bnhb)hehe)333)          | 3434)34
```

I tried regular expressions but since the string size could vary and due to duplicate occurrence I couldn't go much further any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't understand how to split, what the marker is, show more example and how to split it.

Comment: You want to split one string into multiple rows *and* columns? Why are the xyz/efg values for 102 repeated in both rows - if `#abc` is the start of the next 'row', wouldn't one row get the xyz and the other the efg? And how far did you get with your regular expression attempt?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, you'll need **Dynamic SQL**, **Regular Expressions** and **Pivoting**. *Dynamic SQL* to generate the code that will make a table with the appropriate columns (since they're named after the `#___-` and there is an arbitrary number of them). *Pivoting* to pivot a column of values into rows per ID.

I'm used to SQL Server, not Oracle, and the Regex capabilities I use are UDF's since SQL Server doesn't have native Regex capabilities. So my answer is only gonna help so much, but might give you an idea of how to approach this.

I imagine you could built a regex UDF in Oracle, Our regex UDF returns a result-set that I can `join` or in SQL Server's case `cross/outer apply` and it gives me `Value varchar` with the entire match and `SubMatches xml` with the captured submatches:

```
create table #A (data varchar(100));

Insert into #A
  values ('101,#abc-sds)dfgd)3453)#xyz-hju)dddjfj)eieei)2323');
Insert into #A
  values ('102,#abc-ddeff)errr)3434)#xyz-bnhb)hehe)333)#abc-dew)weerr)2343)#efg-3434)34');

declare @cols nvarchar(max), @q nvarchar(max)


    -- Gets found columns comma-separated in @cols:
select @cols = isnull(@cols + ', ', '') + substring(r.Value, 2, len(r.Value)-2)
from #A
cross apply dbo.RegexFind(data, '#(\w+)-', 1, 1, 1) r
group by r.Value


    -- Dynamically create #B with @cols and insert
set @q = N'create table #B(id int, ' + replace(@cols, ', ', ' varchar(255), ') + ' varchar(255))
insert into #B
select p.*
from (
    select r.Value,
        a.SubMatches.value(''(//submatch[@index=0]/@value)[1]'', ''varchar(255)'') col,
        a.SubMatches.value(''(//submatch[@index=1]/@value)[1]'', ''varchar(255)'') val
    from #A
        -- Find the ID at the start
    cross apply dbo.RegexFind(data, ''^\d+'', 1, 1, 1) r
        -- Find any and all #___- occurrences and the text after it
    outer apply dbo.RegexFind(data, ''#(\w+)-([^#]+)'', 1, 1, 1) a
) s
pivot ( -- Pivot dynamically on the found @cols
    min(val) for col in (' + @cols + ')
) p
select * from #B'

exec sp_executesql @q
```

With your example content of table `#A` this gives the following SQL (content of `@q`):

```
create table #B(id int, abc varchar(255), efg varchar(255), xyz varchar(255))
insert into #B
select p.*
from (
    select r.Value,
        a.SubMatches.value('(//submatch[@index=0]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') col,
        a.SubMatches.value('(//submatch[@index=1]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') val
    from #A
        -- Find the ID at the start
    cross apply dbo.RegexFind(data, '^\d+', 1, 1, 1) r
        -- Find any and all #___- occurrences and the text after it
    outer apply dbo.RegexFind(data, '#(\w+)-([^#]+)', 1, 1, 1) a
) s
pivot ( -- Pivot dynamically on the found @cols
    min(val) for col in (abc, efg, xyz)
) p
select * from #B
```

Note though that this `#B` temp table only exists inside the dynamic SQL, I don't know how Oracle handles this.